# Java - Как динамически менять размеры TableView в Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

При создании TableView в оконном приложение для windows, я инициализирую элемент таким образом:

```
//Получить контроллер окна main
Controller_MainGUI controller = this.loader.getController();
        
//Получить tableViewFileName
TableView tableViewFileName = controller.getTableViewFileName();
        
//Получить колонки таблицы
ObservableList<TableColumn<HashMap<String, String>, String>> record = tableViewFileName.getColumns();

//В колонку добавить MapValueFactory
TableColumn<HashMap<String, String>, String> column1 = record.get(0);
MapValueFactory map1 = new MapValueFactory<>("name");
column1.setCellValueFactory(map1);
```

При этом, инициализируя элемент tableView, есть возможность настроить у колонки - column1 свойство, которое отвечает за изменение размера колонки:

```
setResizable(true/false)
```

При этом ничего подобного, что отвечало бы за изменение размеров tableView, если мы хотим растянуть его, не удалось найти.

Есть интересный метод у tableView:

```
setColumnResizePolicy();
```

Опять же он отвечает за работу с колонками и изменение их размеров, но это не относиться к размерам tableView.

При этом моя главная идея заключается в том, чтобы можно было изменять размеры tableView в процессе работы, если потянуть за край объекта таблицы. Например, потянуть за границы, которые показаны на рисунке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что-то подобное можно увидеть, если потянуть за край окна в ОС.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 1: моя таблица - tableView находиться на форме в элементе AnchorPane. Более полная иерархия отражена на рисунке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Подскажите, как можно настроить у tableView свойство, которое отвечает за изменение размеров этого элемента. Может быть есть другие механики или механизмы воздействия на это. Заранее спасибо большое.

Comment: а ты в какой контейнер поместил tableview?

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то моя tableView находиться на AnchorPane.

Comment: Помести в BorderPane и все будет хорошо.
Точнее надо сделать так чтобы у тебя все было в нём

Comment: Попробуй в SplitPane положить таблицу. Она поддерживает изменение размеров. Правда, только в одну сторону.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел определенное решение, которые меня устраивает. Оно полезно, если учитывать то, что мне нужно иметь возможность растягивать таблицу только по вертикали. Данное решение подойдет всем, кто имеет похожие требования.

---

Моя текущая иерархия элементов выглядит таким образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А само окно выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Нужно все необходимые элементы расположить в BorderPane, у которого задать размеры больше начальных размеров окна. Тем самым можно будет растягивая окно от начальных размеров до определенного разрешенного максимального размера. При этом будет изменяться размер BorderPane и внутренних элементов (в моем случае это несколько tableView).

Для этого нужно установить 3 параметра:

1. Максимальный размер окна
2. Минимальный размер окна
3. Начальный размер или размер при инициализации.

Это можно сделать таким кодом:

```
//Установить максимальные размеры окна main
stage.setMaxWidth(780.0);
stage.setMaxHeight(881.0);
    
//Установить минимальные размеры окна main
stage.setMinWidth(780.0);
stage.setMinHeight(352.0);
    
//Установить размеры инициализции окна main
stage.setWidth(780);
stage.setHeight(352);
```

Идея в том, чтобы изменять окно в разрешенном диапазоне значений по оси У ( или параметр "высота"). В моем случае это от 352 до 881. При растягивании окна будут изменяться размеры BorderPane и всех элементов внутри этого элемента, а именно размеры всех таблиц по оси У. При этом будет создаваться ощущение динамического изменения размеров.